# Updating a static array, in a nested function without making a temporary array? <Julia>

Tags: arrays, julia

I have been banging my head against a wall trying to use static arrays in julia.

https://github.com/JuliaArrays/StaticArrays.jl

They are fast but updating them is a pain. This is no surprise, they are meant to be immutable!

But it is continuously recommended to me that I use static arrays even though I have to update them. In my case, the static arrays are small, just length 3, and i have a vector of them, but I only update 1 length three SVector at a time.

---

**Option 1**

There is a really neat package called `Setfield` that allows you to do inplace updates of SVectors in Julia.

https://github.com/jw3126/Setfield.jl

The catch... it updates the local copy. So if you are in a nested function, it updates the local copy. So it comes with some book keeping since you have to inplace update the local copy and then `return` that copy and update the actual array of interest. You can't pass in your desired array and update it in place, at least, not that I can figure out! Now, I do not mind bookeeping, but I feel like updating a local copy, then returning the value, updating another local copy, and then returning the values and finally updating the actual array must come with a speed penalty. I could be wrong.

---

**Option 2**

It bugs me that in order to do an update a static array I must

`exampleSVector::SVector{3,Float64}` <-- just to make clear its type and size

`exampleSVector = [value1, value2, value3]`

This will update the desired array even if it is inside a function, which is nice and the goal, but if you do this inside a function it creates a temporary array. And this kills me because my function is in a loop that gets called 4+ million times, so this creates a ton of allocations and slows things down.

---

***How do I update an `SVector` for the Option 2 scenario without creating a temporary array?***

***For the Option 1 scenario, can I update the actual array of interest rather than the local copy?***

If this requires a simple example code, please say so in the comments, and I will make one. My thinking is that it is answerable without one, but I will make one if it is needed.

### EDIT:

MCVE code - Option 1 works, option 2 does not.

```
using Setfield
using StaticArrays

struct Keep
    dreaming::Vector{SVector{3,Float64}}
end

function INNER!(vec::SVector{3,Float64},pre::SVector{3,Float64})
    # pretend series of calculations
    for i = 1:3 # illustrate use of Setfield (used in real code for this)
        pre = @set pre[i] = rand() * i * 1000
    end

    # more pretend calculations
    x = 25.0 # assume more calculations equals x
################## OPTION 1 ########################
    vec = @set vec = x * [ pre[1], pre[2], pre[3] ] # UNCOMMENT FOR FOR OPTION 1
    return vec                                      # UNCOMMENT FOR FOR OPTION 1

################## OPTION 2 ########################    
    #vec = x * [ pre[1], pre[2], pre[3] ]           # UNCOMMENT FOR FOR OPTION 2
    #nothing                                        # UNCOMMENT FOR FOR OPTION 2

end

function OUTER!(always::Keep)
    preAllocate = SVector{3}(0.0,0.0,0.0)

    for i=1:length(always.dreaming)

        always.dreaming[i] = INNER!(always.dreaming[i], preAllocate) # UNCOMMENT FOR FOR OPTION 1
        #INNER!(always.dreaming[i], preAllocate)                     # UNCOMMENT FOR FOR OPTION 2
    end
end
code = Keep([zero(SVector{3}) for i=1:5])

OUTER!(code)
println(code.dreaming)
```

Comment: I don't understand why you need to mutate. Why don't you just create a new `SVector` each time? For option 2, you write `exampleSVector = SVector(value1, value2, value3)`. No allocations. In your MCVE code, just write `vec = vec .* x`. BTW: `vec` is the name of a function in Base, you shouldn't shadow it.

Comment: I see nothing in your example code to indicate that you need to mutate anything, but if you absolutely must, `MVector` is not that much slower than, `SVector`. In some cases they are almost similar. (Actually, instead of `vec = vec .* x` you can also write `vec *= x`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope that I have understood your question correctly. It's a bit hard with a MWE like this, that does a lot of things that are mostly redundant and a bit confusing.

There seems to be two alternative interpretations here: Either you really need to update ('mutate') an `SVector`, but your MWE fails to demonstrate why. Or, you have convinced yourself that you need to mutate, but you actually don't.

I have decided to focus on alternative 2: You don't really need to 'mutate'. Rewriting your code from that point of view simplifies it greatly.

I couldn't find any reason for you to mutate any static vectors here, so I just removed that. The behaviour of the `INNER!` function with the inputs was very confusing. You provide two inputs but don't use either of them, so I removed those inputs.

```
function inner()
    pre = @SVector [rand() * 1000i for i in 1:3]
    x = 25
    return pre .* x
end

function outer!(always::Keep)
    always.dreaming .= inner.()  # notice the dot in inner.()
end

code = Keep([zero(SVector{3}) for i in 1:5])
outer!(code)
display(code.dreaming)
```

This runs fast and with zero allocations. In general with StaticArrays, don't try to mutate things, just create new instances.

Even though it's not clear from your MWE, there may be some legitimate reason why you may want to 'mutate' an `SVector`. In that case you can use the `setindex` method of StaticArrays, you don't need Setfield.jl:

```
julia> v = rand(SVector{3})
3-element SArray{Tuple{3},Float64,1,3}:
 0.4730258499237898 
 0.23658547518737905
 0.9140206579322541 

julia> v = setindex(v, -3.1, 2)
3-element SArray{Tuple{3},Float64,1,3}:
  0.4730258499237898
 -3.1               
  0.9140206579322541
```

To clarify: `setindex` (without a `!`) does not mutate its input, but creates a new instance with one index value changed.

If you really do need to 'mutate', perhaps you can make a new MWE that shows this. I would recommend that you try to simplify it a bit, because it is quite confusing now. For example, the inclusion of the type `Keep` seems entirely unnecessary and distracting. Just make a `Vector` of `SVector`s and show what you want to do with that.

**Edit:** Here's an attempt based on the comments below. As far as I understand it now, the question is about modifying a vector of `SVector`s. You cannot really mutate the `SVector`s, but you can replace them using a convenient syntax, `setindex`, where you can keep some of the elements and change some of the others:

```
oldvec = [zero(SVector{3}) for _ in 1:5]
replacevec = [rand(SVector{3}) for _ in 1:5]
```

Now we replace the second element of each element of `oldvec` with the corresponding one in `replacevec`. First a one-liner:

```
oldvec .= setindex.(oldvec, getindex.(replacevec, 2), 2)
```

Then an even faster one with a loop:

```
for i in eachindex(oldvec, replacevec)
    @inbounds oldvec[i] = setindex(oldvec[i], replacevec[i][2], 2)
end
```

Comment: The thing with MWE is that they aren't meant to make sense, just emulate the problem. The MWE I posted does this. Changing it changes the problem. However, perhaps the use of two SVectors is the confusion. The one called `pre` is not part of the problem directly. The SVector I am concerned with is `vec`, I include `pre` because `vec` depends on `pre` so I wanted that dependence to be present incase it influenced any solutions. Perhaps I should just make `pre` a normal `Vector` for the example?

Comment: the issue I have in the real code is that updating `vec` by going `vec = x * [pre[1], pre[2], pre[3] ]` where undergoes several calculations to be determined... this allocates a temporary array. I don't know why, but it does, and it does it every time `INNER` is called. these allocations add up and slow down the entire code. I get around it by using my Option 1. However, I don't like that I can't use option 2. there should be a way to either update or replace `vec` entirely in `INNER` without resorting to special packages. I am convinced I am held back only by my own ignorance.

Comment: I have made many methods which update `vec` in inner, however it doesn't update the respective values in `always.dreaming`.

Comment: I think the problem isn't that your MWE doesn't make sense. MWEs rarely do. The problem is that your MWE isn't actually _minimal_. It does a lot of extra stuff, and it's hard to find out what is important and what isn't. Ideally, an MWE should should not be possible to change trivially, so that you still achieve the same effect. Is it possible to update it, and peel away the cruft (starting with the type `Keep`, which is entirely irrelevant)?

Comment: my design decision is to use a struct to hold all data. holding things in arrays versus arrays held in a struct is a different problem. Getting changes to carry all the way down to the struct is part of my problem. It is easy to change the local arrays, but the changes don't carry down to the struct

Comment: First of all, you cannot update or mutate `vec`, you can only replace it. I've used the word 'mutate', because it just _fakes_ mutation, it actually replaces the whole thing. `INNER!(always.dreaming[i], preAllocate)` will never work. The elements of `always.dreaming` cannot be mutated, you can only mutate `always.dreaming` itself. `vec = x * [pre[1], pre[2], pre[3] ]` allocates because `[pre[1], pre[2], pre[3] ]` is an ordinary `Vector` which is allocated each time.

Comment: You have more or less answered my question though. It was really about updating my length 3 `SVectors` without needing to use `@set`. Which is why I didn't include a MWE the first time around :)

Comment: It's fine to use a struct, but you're not using that struct in the MWE. Your MWE only works on `always.dreaming` which is an array. The fact that that array is contained in a struct is irrelevant, and a distraction.

Comment: having static arrays in an immutable struct seems like a huge pain since nothing in the struct can actually be updating without carrying the ripples all the way back through all the functions. I am a little exhausted with trying to make static arrays work cleanly when mutable arrays are just straight forward

Comment: It's a different way of thinking, indeed. Having static arrays directly in an immutable struct makes them hard to update, yes. But static arrays inside an ordinary vector inside an immutable struct is not a problem. You mutate the vector of svectors, by replacing the elements of the outer vector. Think of an svector as a scalar. You cannot update a scalar, just replace it. It's the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

There are two types of static arrays - mutable (starting with `M` in type name) and immutable ones (starting with `S`) - just use the mutable ones! have a look at the example below:

```
julia> mut = MVector{3,Int64}(1:3);

julia> mut[1]=55
55

julia> mut
3-element MArray{Tuple{3},Int64,1,3}:
 55
  2
  3

julia> immut = SVector{3,Int64}(1:3);

julia> inmut[1]=55
ERROR: setindex!(::SArray{Tuple{3},Int64,1,3}, value, ::Int) is not defined.
```

Let us see some simple benchmark (ordinary array, vs mutable static vs immutable static):

```
using BenchmarkTools

julia> ord = [1,2,3];

julia> @btime $ord.*$ord;
  39.680 ns (1 allocation: 112 bytes)
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 4
 9



julia> @btime $mut.*$mut
  8.533 ns (1 allocation: 32 bytes)
3-element MArray{Tuple{3},Int64,1,3}:
 3025
    4
    9


julia> @btime $immut.*$immut
  2.133 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
3-element SArray{Tuple{3},Int64,1,3}:
 1
 4
 9
```

Comment: I keep being told to use the static ones though... They are allegedly faster?

Comment: Yes - they are faster but I understand you need the mutable ones. I updated my answer with a benchmark. It is often faster to create a new immutable object discarding the old one than to manipulate the state of a mutable one,